# How to get form input fields if name is not known

Tags: php, jquery, html

I have a form which is made dynamically with jquery ajax and input fields names values comes dynamically, I want to update these fields with php I am not sure how to do this.

when form is submitted I does not know what will be the name of input fields.

```
<form id="modalform" action="#" method="post">
 <input type="text" name="46" class="form-control margin-top20 " value="selcetopt 1" />
 <input type="text" name="50" class="form-control margin-top20 " value="selcetopt 2" />
 <input type="text" name="56" class="form-control margin-top20 " value="selcetopt 3" />
 <input type="text" name="66" class="form-control margin-top20 " value="selcetopt 4" />
 <input type="text" name="96" class="form-control margin-top20 " value="selcetopt 5" />
<input type="submit" value="Update" name="submit" />
 </form>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can iterate over `$_POST` to get all input filed values, Based on your question I have added a sample code below

```
<?php
if(!empty($_POST)){
    foreach($_POST as $key => $value){
        // Preprocess $key which holds name of input field
        // You can apply your logic to process value for an input $key here 
        // From your example it looks like name is a number so special case can check within a condition for $key as number

        if(ctype_digit($key)){
            // This will only get the value of all dynamic input fields if name is a number     
        }
    }
}
```

I hope it helps you

Answer (score 0):

See if that helps in any way, create a form like that

```
<form onsubmit="return submitForm(this);">

    <input data-key="field-1" value="" />
    <input data-key="field-2" value="" />
    <input data-key="field-3" value="" />
    ...
    <button type="submit">Submit form</button>

</form>
```

JQuery code:

```
var form_data = {};

function parseInputs(form) {

    $(form).find("input").each(function() {
        form_data[$(this).data("key")] = $(this).val();
    })

    return form_data;
}

function submitForm(form) {

    var options = {

        type: "POST",

        url: "form_handling.php",

        data: parseInputs(form),

        success: function (response) {alert(response)}

    };

    $.ajax(options);

    return false;

}
```

And `form_handling.php` would be:

```
<?php

foreach($_POST as $key => $value) {

    echo $key . " = " . $value;

}

?>
```